# unable to Import package 'from chatbase import Messgae'?

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, chatbase

> hi there I'm currently facing this issue Unable to installed properly chatbase its give me module error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/home/dellvostro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatbase/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from chatbase.facebook_agent_message import *   File "/home/dellvostro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatbase/facebook_agent_message.py", line 19, in <module>
from base_message import Message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_message'
```

please help me,I m following this link [click](https://github.com/google/chatbase-python) I was also used both pip and pip3 to installed the package chronological order.
thanks